# Open source data mining package comparsion

Tags: classification, data-mining, model-comparison

Is there sources where I can see performance of different ML models applied to same data?

Currently I want to understand performance percision/recall difference between mahout online logistic regression vs Mallet MaxEnt, LibLINIEAR.

Comment: I would probably start with google scholar, and look for evaluation of learning algorithms for the particular ones you are interested in. Many of them are available in PDF form without an academic subscription